# Does the ClassMapAutoloader need to be defined in every Module in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, configuration-files, autoload, zend-autoloader

Since the dynamic class loading with `Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader` is very expensive, I [generate](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.loader.classmap-generator.html) a classmap and set it in the

**`Application\Module`**

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return [
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../../data/cache' . '/' . 'autoload_classmap.application.php',
        ],
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => [
            'namespaces' => [
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                'MyNamespace' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/my/lib/src'
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

The file `autoload_classmap.application.php` contains a classmap for `/module` and `/vendor/my/lib/src`.

**Is it enough to extend the `getAutoloaderConfig()` of only one module (e.g. `Application`) or do I need to do that in every the `ClassMapAutoloader`?**

Comment: No, you can use composer and get rid of the ZF2 auto-loading.

Comment: You mean just add (`php classmap_generator.php ... -a`) my classes to the `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`?

Comment: `php composer.phar dumpautoload` check out the [autoloading documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading); it will require that you have the namespaces defined in a `composer.json` file.